# Why do kernels have a main thread

Tags: c, multithreading, kernel

I'm working on a simplistic preemptive kernel implemented in C which places the main path of execution in a thread which it calls 'Main Thread'.
A thread is composed of a stack and a `struct thread containing:

> ```
> tid_t tid;                          /* Thread identifier. */
> enum thread_status status;          /* Thread state. */
> char name[16];                      /* Name (for debugging purposes). */
> uint8_t *stack;                     /* Saved stack pointer. */
> int priority;                       /* Priority. */
> struct list_elem allelem;           /* List element for all threads list. */
> unsigned magic;                     /* Detects stack overflow. */
> ```

And some other components which are irrelevant.

The part I don't understand is why the main path of execution is bound to an entire thread? As I understand it, the main path of execution is the CPU 'unmasked' doing initialization and thread swaping. Everything else is done by threads which are the CPU wearing different 'masks'.
Now, why would the main path of execution need to have all the components of a thread? It only needs registers(which are incorporated into the CPU) and a stack(which can be managed from software).
So isn't the `struct thread` part redundant for it? It only needs one part of a thread:the stack.

Comment: "*As I understand it, the main path of execution is the CPU 'unmasked' doing initialization and thread swaping.*" I can't figure out what that could possibly mean.

Comment: What do you mean by "main path of execution?" That to me is not clear, but I can see useful information in the other members of the struct (i.e. magic, for overflow, name, for debugging and priority, for your scheduler).

Comment: Why make a lot of special cases and code for the "main path" of execution, when there's already all the mechanisms in place for doing so and you can treat that execution path just as another thread. Surely that main thread must obey most of the same rules as other threads, e.g. be suspended so another thread can run, wait on mutexes, and so on.

Comment: The closest thing to a "main thread" I can think of in a kernel is the process scheduler... after initialization, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing here,'cos your question is a little unclear...

Your 'Main Path Of Execution' is what runs at boot time and, (amongst other things), initializes the scheduler, memory-manager, drivers etc. of your OS.  Typically, it will then wish to start up shells, logon-manager threads, service managers, loadable drivers etc..  These entities require the services of the kernel to run up - the MPOE cannot just call them.  So, at this point it must arrange for the kernel to manage threads of execution while still running on itself.  So, the MPOE creates a thread-control block for itself, allocates itself a stack, initialises the stack/TCB to look like a thread that has been interrupted, points the saved stack pointer to its own code that will run the remainder of the system boot and interrupt-returns to itself.  It is now a single kernel-managed thread and it can load/run essential drivers, (that enable their hardware interrupts), and then load startup processes, (the loader creates a thread to initially run processes, just like loading a user process), and so your OS outer layers boot up in parallel with the MPOE as it continues to start stuff up.

When all the boot-time OS processes drivers, services etc. are all running, the MPOE can simply terminate itself - it's now just a thread, after all.

Summary - the MPOE has to arrange for itself to be managed by the kernel, as a thread, before it has completed its work.  It must, therefore, have thread-control structures so that it can be managed in the same way as any other thread.

It needs more than registers(which are incorporated into the CPU) and it must have a stack which can be managed from the kernel.  If this does not happen, the OS higher-level components that it starts cannot run up in parallel with it.

NOTE: OS experts please forgive me for being economical with the horrible complexity :)